# How do you store user input as a variable in c?

Tags: c, variables, input, store

I am a very newbie programmer, and have no clue whatsoever what I'm doing. besides reading documentation.

My program isn't giving the user time to input the unwires right away, its just saying the answer for no. What did I do wrong?

I made this program to be a funny joke for my friends (like an AI gone wrong)

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int yorn;

    printf("do you have friends? please awnser yes or no.");
    scanf("%d", &yorn );

    if (yorn = "yes") {
        printf("no, you dont. please reload the program if you want to change your awnser.");
    }
    else if (yorn = "no") {
        printf("i can be your friend. your BEST friend.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It depends what type of input.  (Pun intended, the type of your variable and the type of you describe your users typing do not match)

Comment: True @BenVoigt. I have made answer to suggest him the changes.

Comment: Compiling with warnings enabled would have revealed multiple issues here (misuse of single `=` and assignment of pointer value to an integer). It's worth learning how to configure your compiler for the maximum warning level (`-Wall` in `gcc`) and always pay attention to warnings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For comparison, you have two use `strcmp` not `=`. Also, you are taking `int` type for `yorn` and comparing with the string. Change yorn type to `char[]` and read as `%s` in `scanf`.

Change your code to following the code. look closely to understand it:

```
int main() {

    char yorn[20]; //set max size according to your need

    printf("do you have friends? please awnser yes or no.");
    scanf("%19s", yorn); // Use %s here to read string.

    if (strcmp(yorn, "yes") == 0) { //Use ==
        printf("no, you dont. please reload the program if you want to change your awnser.");
    }
    else if (strcmp(yorn,"no") == 0) { // Use ==
        printf("i can be your friend. your BEST friend.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't compare strings directly in C. Use strcmp string operation.

Comment: Now it will compile, but those `==` operators will do a pointer comparison, without regard for the strings stored at those locations.

Comment: And you added a bug for when somebody enters more than 20 characters.

Comment: @DanielH As the answer is for beginners. I haven't used the concept of the pointer and memory allocation.

Comment: @PassionInfinite It doesn't take much knowledge to understand that if you declare it as a `char[20]`, you need to say `%19s` in `scanf`.